# Some commands does not work in su envirorment

Tags: su, sshd

I have logged in to CentOS 5 machine with normal user and then I used su command to login as root user. Now commands like ifconfig, useradd, userdel are not working on machine and it gives command not found error.

But those commands work if I login direct with root user.

Comment: Command not found errors mean that the commands cannot be found. That has most likely to do with your PATH. That doesn't imply that they are not working, just that your environment is not correct. **Update the question** with the values from `echo $PATH` for both cases (`su` and direct login)

Comment: Have you tried using `su -` to log into the root account? This should correctly read in all of the root users environment.

Comment: @geedoubleya Yes I have logged in using `su -` command. But it was giving error but then I checked `echo $PATH` so the /sbin and /usr/sbin was missing there. It worked when I added those paths. Thanks for Help :)